# Puma Pool Usage in (new) Ruby Language Metrics (Heroku)

Tags: heroku

I recently enabled the beta Ruby Language Metrics in Heroku ([docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-ruby#puma-pool-usage))

I have 2 Performance-M web dynos running. The Puma pool metrics are below.

The usage seems unexpectedly low to me over the first 2 hours of this enabled. Am I missing something, or are these numbers somewhat expected?

[Puma Pool Usage Metrics screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSIGu.png)

Answer (score 0):

So did I recently. I believe what you are seeing is simply that there are no data for that time frame. This view corresponds to what I see before the deploy that activated the metrics.